# Tokenizing a corpus composed of articles into sentences Python

Tags: python, deep-learning, gensim, word2vec

I will like to analyze my first deep learning model using Python and in order to do so I have to first split my corpus (8807 articles) into sentences. My corpus is built as follows:

```
## Libraries to download
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
from gensim import corpora, models
import gensim

import json
import nltk
import re
import pandas


appended_data = []


#for i in range(20014,2016):
#    df0 = pandas.DataFrame([json.loads(l) for l in open('SDM_%d.json' % i)])
#    appended_data.append(df0)

for i in range(2005,2016):
    if i > 2013:
        df0 = pandas.DataFrame([json.loads(l) for l in open('SDM_%d.json' % i)])
        appended_data.append(df0)
    df1 = pandas.DataFrame([json.loads(l) for l in open('Scot_%d.json' % i)])
    df2 = pandas.DataFrame([json.loads(l) for l in open('APJ_%d.json' % i)])
    df3 = pandas.DataFrame([json.loads(l) for l in open('TH500_%d.json' % i)])
    df4 = pandas.DataFrame([json.loads(l) for l in open('DRSM_%d.json' % i)])
    appended_data.append(df1)
    appended_data.append(df2)
    appended_data.append(df3)
    appended_data.append(df4)


appended_data = pandas.concat(appended_data)
# doc_set = df1.body

doc_set = appended_data.body
```

I am trying to use the function `Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format` from the library `gensim.models` but I have to first split my corpus (`doc_set`) into sentences.

```
from gensim.models import word2vec
model = Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format(doc_set, binary=False)
```

Any recommendations?

cheers

Comment: do you want to run doc2vec or word2vec? As far as I know `load_word2vec_format` loads a trained word2vec model in the C word2vec-tool format.

Comment: Good point @Alvaro Marco, as far as I am aware, the only way I have seen to build a deep learning model is through the function Word2Vec

Comment: I think I understood your problem now. So you should call `Word2Vec(doc_set)` where `doc_set` is a list of tokenized sentences (list of lists). Is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, Gensim's `Word2Vec` requires this format for its training input: `sentences = [['first', 'sentence'], ['second', 'sentence']]`.

I assume your documents contain more than one sentence. You should first split by sentences, you can do that with [nltk](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#module-nltk.tokenize.punkt) (you might need to download the model first). Then tokenize each sentence and put everything together in a list.

```
sent_detector = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
sentenized = doc_set.body.apply(sent_detector.tokenize)
sentences = itertools.chain.from_iterable(sentenized.tolist()) # just to flatten

result = []
for sent in sentences:
    result += [nltk.word_tokenize(sent)]
gensim.models.Word2Vec(result)
```

Unfortunately I am not good enough with Pandas to perform all the operations in a "pandastic" way.

Pay a lot of attention to the parameters of `Word2Vec` picking them right can make a huge difference.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, there seem to be little problems but I will solve them. Cheers!

Comment: Sure, please post your final solution. I would be very interested to check it out and ask if you have any other doubt, maybe I can help

Comment: It was a stupid mistake of mine, works perfect! thanks a lot mate, really good coding!

Comment: ah, good then! And as I said before the parameters play a big role, keep that in mind.